# Has someone a convenient solution to determine if a Spring-Kafka-Consumer is listening

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am looking for a convenient solution to determine if a Spring-Kafka-Consumer is listening.
We are using a KafkaListenerContainerFactory to create our listener container and now we want to check if it is connected to the broker and listening to the topic(s).

Could someone please help out i found nothing in the internet that works.
messageListenerContainer.isRunning() does show true even if the broker isnt available so that doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

You can examine the consumer metrics and inspect them, for example:

```
MetricName [name=network-io-total, group=consumer-metrics, description=The total number of network operations (reads or writes) on all connections
MetricName [name=connection-count, group=consumer-metrics, description=The current number of active connections.
```

There are other metrics that might be useful, e.g `last-poll-seconds-ago`.

```java
/**
 * Return metrics kept by this container's consumer(s), grouped by {@code client-id}.
 * @return the consumer(s) metrics grouped by {@code client-id}
 * @since 1.3
 * @see org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.Consumer#metrics()
 */
Map<String, Map<MetricName, ? extends Metric>> metrics();
```

Comment: Is connection-count consistent or are new connections created and closed from time to time and changing this metric.

By the way thank you so far ;)

Comment: The documentation says "number of active connections" so I would assume the latter. https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#selector_monitoring